# Parse single values from HttpResponse

Tags: c#, json, http

In making a call to the Google Geolocation API, the results (json) are returned like so

**Example** (Apologies, I couldn't get the Json to format properly)

```
{"geocoded_waypoints" : [
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "EiQ3LCA3IExha2VzaWRlIERyLCBSeWUsIE5ZIDEwNTgwLCBVU0EiHRobChYKFAoSCQH00P0vl8KJEQ2d7mWAl0jrEgE3",
     "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
  },
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJ1YqpR4eRwokRTuazxMrnKiM",
     "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
  }   ],
"routes" : [{
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 41.0044903,
           "lng" : -73.6892836
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 40.9575099,
           "lng" : -73.7589093
        }
     },
     "copyrights" : "Map data ©2018 Google",
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "7.0 mi",
              "value" : 11325
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "15 mins",
              "value" : 889
           },
           "end_address" : "851 Fenimore Rd, Mamaroneck, NY 10543, USA",
           "end_location" : {
              "lat" : 40.9575099,
              "lng" : -73.75338219999999
           },
           "start_address" : "7 Pheasant Run #7, Rye, NY 10580, USA",
           "start_location" : {
              "lat" : 40.99850199999999,
              "lng" : -73.689633
           },
```

There are various single items I need to retrieve from the returned data, for example, the  duration:text value.
Is there a way to filter out the excess in the API call or how do I parse this from the Json?

I tried deserializing to an object to then iterate over it and grab the legs array, but A. that doesn't work as the object is on big item, not a collection and B. that seems wasteful.

```
 public int TravelTimeInMinutes(string origin, string destination, string apiKey)
    {
        var timeToTravel = 0;

        var url = DirectionsUrlBase + ConvertOriginFormat(origin) + ConvertDestinationFormat(destination) + "&key="+ apiKey;
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // Add the Accept type header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // get the response
        // make method async once working
         var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;   
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Parse the response body.
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result());
            dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            foreach (var item in array)
            {

            }
          //… rest removed for brevity
```

How can I drill down to retrieve single values? I think my error is in how I am deserializing the response. I also have a Duration class with Text and Value properties. I would like to deserialize to that class if possible.

**Follow up**

I added `.Result` after the serialize call
    `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result()`

this is now returning proper json

[image: Json Returned]

Now how can I parse single values from this or can I deserialize into the Duration class.
Per Charles suggestion

I have a root object

public class MapsDirectionObject
    {
        public GeocodedWaypoints[] geocoded_waypoints { get; set; }
        public Routes[] routes { get; set; }
    }

```
public class Routes
{
    public object[] Value { get; set; }
}

public class GeocodedWaypoints
{
    public string geocoder_status { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
}
```

And since the returned json only has two main children, routes and waypoints, I have those classes as well. The deserialization errors with the following error.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "{   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
>         {

If I remove the .Result call on the serialization, I can map to that object but the values are null.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I'd prefer we do strongly typed deserialization, so let's create classes corresponding to the data we need from the JSON:

```
public class ResultData
{
    [JsonProperty("routes")]
    public List<Route> Routes { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    [JsonProperty("legs")]
    public List<Leg> Legs { get; set; }
}

public class Leg
{
    [JsonProperty("duration")]
    public Duration Duration { get; set; }
}

public class Duration
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

then we deserialize the JSON:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = client.GetAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=7+7+Lakeside+Dr+Rye+NY&destination=Winged+Winged+Foot+Golf+Club").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var desed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultData>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    var durations = desed.Routes.SelectMany(r => r.Legs.Select(l => l.Duration)).ToList();
    durations.ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine($"T: {d.Text}, V: {d.Value}"));
}
```

### Note:

skip the serialization step ... `ReadAsStringAsync()` should produce a valid JSON string

Comment: Neither of the above methods work (both answers). I get the error that it cannot convert the data

Comment: @dinotom try using `JsonProperty' attribute

Comment: can you please offer a valid json to test ?

Comment: @dinotom I noticed there is a root object called `Result` I changed the answer as needed

Comment: I posted the full json

Comment: … your edited answer still produces the same error..paste this url in your browser and you should get the return json ...https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=7+7+Lakeside+Dr+Rye+NY&destination=Winged+Winged+Foot+Golf+Club

Comment: {System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Marshals2020.Services.CoordinateService.DirectionsObject.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization   .As I said earler, I think the error is in the SERIALIZATION...did you try the link I pasted in the prior comment to see the actual returned json?

Comment: I updated the answer ... skip the serialization step ... `ReadAsStringAsync()` should produce a valid json string

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please post a complete valid JSON object on your answer.

You uses Visual Studio for coding right? You can use **Paste Special** for help you:

1) Copy your entire JSON to clipboard;

2) Open your class file on Visual Studio;

3) Go to menu "Edit > Paste Special > Paste as JSON Class";

4) You will got something like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Geocoded_Waypoints[] geocoded_waypoints { get; set; }
}

public class Geocoded_Waypoints
{
    public string geocoder_status { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize to a typed object:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result);

foreact(var geocoded_waypoints in myObject.geocoded_waypoints)
{
    // do something with geocoded_waypoints
}

// your duration object:
var duration = myObject.routes[0].legs[0].duration;
```

If you want you can rename **Rootobject** to any name you want, like **Geolocation**.

Comment: ...I don't have a complete object for the return as the return data is much more than I need. Love to know if it is filterable, such as a way to request on the legs:duration data. I have a duration class. See my follow up addition to the OP

Comment: Do the steps with the full JSON file, you will have all the tree of objects, you will need it for deserialization, after get only what you need and maybe put in another model

Comment: Also, I don't have a Paste Special option on my edit menu

Comment: What version o VS you are using? See this to fix: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4dccf2b7-af71-4e17-9ba4-cdc4ea9ba0c3/visual-studio-2017-enterprise-missing-edit-paste-special-paste-json-as-classes?forum=vssetup

Comment: VS 2017 Professional